# Scaling a object is not working

Tags: modeling, unreal-engine

I am trying to make something bigger in blender With the S key but it is not working.

[image: I want this to work in Unreal engine so these are my Unit Presets]

So maybe you guys can help me fix this problem, That would be appreciated!
Feel free to ask me question if that helps.

Comment: Hello! For basic scaling, you do not need the "Unit" settings. To scale a whole object, make sure you are in object mode (press tab key to toggle)

Comment: ow wow, how stupid of me! Thanks man for the help!

Comment: No problem! I will add this as an answer then (as this is actually the answer).

Comment: It is generally a right thing to do before exporting to any 3rd party software - setting up units. However unit system by itslef won't change much for the scale of the object, it only creates standard reference. Scale the object and make to always apply scale with Ctrl+A > Scale and Rotation in Object mode

Answer (score 1):

For basic scaling, you do not need the "Unit" settings. To scale a whole object, make sure you are in object mode (press tab key to toggle).